# Reassigning imports.env.memory for WebAssembly module doesn't replace heap

Tags: multithreading, webassembly

I am developing an in-browser player for a proprietary video format. Our old player was a Chrome NaCl plugin, while the replacement is to be implemented in JavaScript and WebAssembly.

The video decode is to be done in a pipeline using two webworkers, both managing WASM modules. One worker does zlib decompression, while the other decodes the pixels. It's important for performance to avoid buffer copies. So my proposed pipeline is this:

- In main JS thread, allocate a new WebAssembly.Memory object and fill it with data from the video feed.
- Hand off ownership to the decompress worker.
- Replace the heap for its WASM module with the new memory.
- Call the decompress function.
- Detach the heap from this module and transfer ownership to the decode worker.
- Replace the heap for this WASM module with the new memory.
- Call the decode function.
- Detach the heap from this module and transfer ownership back to the main thread for WebGL display.

To see if I could do this, I set up an experiment as follows:

C code for the WASM module:

```
void decode(unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out)
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        *out++ = *in++ + 100;
    }
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
emcc test_wasm.c -O3 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_decode']" -o test_wasm.wasm
```

And this is the JS code that loads it:

export class LoadWasm {
    wasmOnLoad(obj) {
        this.instance = obj.instance;
        console.log("Loaded WASM");
        console.log(obj.instance);

```
    // Fill buffer with some numbers
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        this.heap[i] = i;
    }
    // Have WASM code copy the data, adding 100 to each number
    obj.instance.exports._decode(0, 128);
    // Print output
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log(i + ": " + this.heap[i] + " => " + this.heap[i+128]);
    }

    // Allocate a new heap for the WASM module
    this.memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 256
    });
    this.heap = new Uint8Array(this.memory.buffer);
    // Replace the WASM module's heap
    this.imports.env.memory = this.memory;

    // Fill the heap with new data
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        this.heap[i] = i+10;
    }
    // Run the compute again
    obj.instance.exports._decode(0, 128);
    // Print out the results
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log(i + ": " + this.heap[i] + " => " + this.heap[i+128]);
    }
}

constructor() {
    this.memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 256
    });
    this.heap = new Uint8Array(this.memory.buffer);
    this.imports = {
        env: {
            __memory_base: 0,
            memory: this.memory,
            abort: function(err) {
                throw new Error('abort ' + err);
            },
        }
    };
}

start() {
    console.log("startWasm");
    WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('test_wasm.wasm'), this.imports)
        .then(this.wasmOnLoad.bind(this));
}
```

}

And it's invoked from my main HTML page like this:

```
import { LoadWasm } from "./test_wasm.js";
var l = new LoadWasm();
l.start();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The first call to `_decode` works fine. And it works fine again if I don't replace the heap. But if I do replace the heap, I only get back zeros. The WASM module isn't using the new heap.

Because there is no shared memory (yet) between webworkers and the main JS thread, the only way to transfer data zero-copy between webworkers is handing off ownership of objects. As a result, I can't do the obvious thing and pass around and fill subarrays of the existing heap. I need to be able to fill a new heap while doing processing on the previous one, in order to get the required parallelism.

To solve this, I can think of a few options:

**Option 1:** Is there a way to replace the heap of an already-instantiated WASM module, and I'm just doing it wrong?

**Option 2:** Maybe I can create a new instance of the WASM module for each frame to decode. But how do I load and compile the WASM code only once and keep reusing it? I think it still has to go through a linking process, though. How much overhead is there to do this? Is it worth it?

**Option 3:** I understand that WASM supports threads already. I could request a decode to occur in the main JS thread, and inside the WASM code, it would hand off the computation to a worker thread. The problem is finding out when the computation is done. Is there a way to do a postMessage from a non-main thread in WASM? It seems that if I were to try to call a JS function from a non-main WASM thread, that would probably fail or crash the browser.

Are there any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Option 2: Maybe I can create a new instance of the WASM module for each frame to decode. But how do I load and compile the WASM code only once and keep reusing it?

Modules are compiled, not instances.  So every new instance is reusing the compiled module.